# How to group/bucket a list of tuples based on certain text criteria?

Tags: python, list, tuples, python-itertools

I have a list of tuples and some of the tuples have 'start' and 'end' as the first item in the tuple. I'd like to bucket the list of tuples into a list of list of tuples in which the sublists are grouped by whether they fall between a tuple with a 'start' in the first item and an 'end' in the first item.

```
list = [('start',1),('item_1',4),('item_2',2),('end',1),('start',10),('item_1',5),('item_3',2),('end',1),('start',10),('item_1',5),('item_3',2),('item_3',9),('end',1)]]

desired_result =  [[('start',1),('item_1',4),('item_2',2),('end',1)],[('start',10),('item_1',5),('item_3',2),('end',1)],[('start',10),('item_1',5),('item_3',9),('item_3',2),('end',1)]]
```

I'm trying to utilize groupby and itemgetter with little success:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

[list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(list), itemgetter('start','end')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need extra for modules for this.

I suppose that "end" is followed by "start", so no need to look for "end".

Just compute indexes of items containing `"start"`

```
indexes = [i for i,e in enumerate(lst) if e[0]=='start']
```

then build the sublists using slicing with special case for last element to include last list

```
result = [lst[indexes[i]:indexes[i+1] if i<len(indexes)-1 else len(lst)] for i in range(len(indexes))]
```

result:

```
[[('start', 1), ('item_1', 4), ('item_2', 2), ('end', 1)], [('start', 10), ('item_1', 5), ('item_3', 2), ('end', 1)], [('start', 10), ('item_1', 5), ('item_3', 2), ('item_3', 9), ('end', 1)]]
```

which is the `desired_result` except for items order but I respect the original list order so that must be a typo in your expected result

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `enumerate`, `zip` and `iter` functions:

```
list1 = [('start',1),('item_1',4),('item_2',2),('end',1),('start',10),('item_1',5),('item_3',2),('end',1),('start',10),('item_1',5),('item_3',2),('item_3',9),('end',1)]

grouped_list = [list1[r[0]:r[1]+1]
                for r in list(zip(*[iter([k for k,t in enumerate(list1)
                                          if t[0] in ('start','end')])] * 2))]

print(grouped_list)
```

The output:

```
[[('start', 1), ('item_1', 4), ('item_2', 2), ('end', 1)], [('start', 10), ('item_1', 5), ('item_3', 2), ('end', 1)], [('start', 10), ('item_1', 5), ('item_3', 2), ('item_3', 9), ('end', 1)]]
```

*Details*:

- `zip(*[iter(sequence)] * n))` will pull an item from the iterator(presented with `iter(sequence)`) and make a tuple of 2 items which point to indices from `start` to `end`(consecutively)
- `list1[r[0]:r[1]+1]` will get a slice of items for each `start`-`end` boundaries range

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.groupby` is a sorting function.  It won't help you in this.  Probably the best way is to do it manually:

```
new_list = []
for item in old_list:
    if item[0] == 'start':
        new_list.append([item])
    else:
        new_list[-1].append(item)
```

Note that it will error if the first tuple is not a starter.  It will also ignore ending points, so any tuple that is not between a start and end will be added to the same list as the last end.  If you want to catch all the problems there might be, it's a little bit more complicated:

```
new_list = []
in_list = False
for item in old_list:
    if item[0] == 'start':
        if in_list:
            raise ValueError("The last list hasn't completed yet.")
        new_list.append([item])
        in_list = True
    else:
        if item[0] == 'end':
            if not in_list:
                raise ValueError("The list has already completed.")
            in_list = False

        # If this is a problem, it will throw its own error
        new_list[-1].append(item)
```